# Vim in Emacs

Tags: macos, vim, emacs

*The question does not refer to some Vim-mode in Emacs, but to Vim inside Emacs. I am not waging any Editor-war. I just want to use Vim in Emacs.*

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175588/emacs.png

You can get to Vim in Emacs with commands "M-x term" and "vim".

When I am using the Vim-Emacs, the typing is awkward. There are odd signs, such as "4m", "4mm" and "^?^?". The backspace and the x-button in insert mode do not work. The odd signs emerge when I press the latter keys. So

> How can I get Vim properly working in Emacs?

**[Updated Information]**

The malfunctioning Vim-Emacs is at least in the following OSs:

- Mac OS 10.5.6

Comment: Just tried it and could not reproduce it. The typing is OK, no odd signs, backspace works. This Ubuntu 9.04, GNU Emacs 22.2.1, vim 7.2.

Comment: kastauyra: I tested the Vim-Emacs in Mac's terminal. I will test it as a separate Emacs.

Comment: The same errors occur in the separate Emacs. Mac OS 10.5.6.

Comment: kastauyra: You are right. I tested the thing in my VM Ubuntu, and it did not occur there. Clearly, it is a Mac-specific bug or something.

Comment: What terminal type does vim see? Here in Emacs term I get:
$ echo $TERM
eterm-color

Comment: I'd agree with kastauyra that it looks like a terminal type issue. I've seen this before when running stuff in Emacs and the Emacs terminal emulator didn't support all the functionality the contained process needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is that the terminal setting $TERM in your shell/Vim session doesn't match what the EMACS terminal is doing.  Mine works fine, with the exception that the delete key is mapped to DEL, 0x127, while Vim wants ^H, 0x8.  Mine shows the $TERM setting to be "eterm-color".

Check what you have as $TERM

> $ echo $TERM

and check the Vim docs for how to fix the backspace issue.

Comment: Okay, it's probably being set by some x-specific stuff somewhere.  I'm running Mac OS/X 10.5.6, Intel, and a fairly old Carbon EMACS, July of last year.  Try setting your Vim terminal type explicitly and see if it's better.

Answer (score 0):

For backspace,

```
stty crt erase <CTRL-V><BACKSPACE>
```

Worked for me.

As for the rest, I don't know.  Suppose it is something the shell outputs that the terminal doesn't handle.  (Never used emacs 'term' before... prefer iTerm or Terminal.app for shell-related stuff.  emacs 'term' has been called an "imperfect terminal emulator")